# Display search count in IdeaVim

Tags: webstorm, rider, ideavim

Below is the UI of Rider search with <kbd>Cmd + F</kbd>. But I'm using the IdeaVim plugin, I want a similar UI to count the current match when I perform a search with `/` or `?` but can't find the config to display it.

[image: Rider search count view]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I'm getting this correctly then this is not possible right now (not implemented).

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/VIM-2544 -- watch this ticket (star/vote/comment) to get notified with any progress.

Comment: I see, that feature is not available for now, I will wait for it to be implemented.

Comment: @Finn Yeah. Sadly it has no votes (only 1 so far) so may not be on their "what to implement next" list. Make sure you have voted for that ticket. May even ask friends to extra votes (if they also would like to have such feature).